# Subgroups of the alternating groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

The question reads as follows:

Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $A_6$ with index $|A_6: H| \leq 4$. By considering the cosets $H\sigma ^i$, show that any 5-cycle $\sigma$ belongs
to $H$.
Hence, show that $H = A_6$.

I know that through using Lagrange's theorem the order of $H$ is greater than or equal to 90, and that $A_6$ is a simple group. But I'm not sure how to use the cosets to verify containment.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: How can a $5$-cycle act on $4$ cosets?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @DerekHolt is this a criticism of the question or a hint?

Comment: A hint! The group acts by multiplication on the four cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: yes, so let x be a 5 cycle not in H, then consider H, xH,  ... . then since this is a group of order less than or equal to 4, at least two of the cosets are equal. But this is not possible and hence contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see, two of the cosets $H\sigma^i\ (i=0,\dots,4)$ for a 5-cycle $\sigma$ must coincide since $|A_6\colon H|\leq 4$. Namely $H\sigma^i=H\sigma^j$ for some $i<j<5$ and $H\sigma^{j-i}=H$, $\sigma^{j-i}\in H$, hence $\sigma\in H$ follows.

Thus, $H$ contains all 144 5-cycles in $A_6$ and so $H$ has 36 5-Sylow subgroups. By index assumption, $H$ is of order 360, 180, 120 or 90. The latter two are not multiples of 36 so impossible. The second case is where $H$ is of index two and so normal in $A_6$, thus impossible by simplicity. Therefore $H=A_6$.